# How to do Pivot in MySQL where only one column is the base of the query

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I saw a lot of ways on how to do pivot in MySQL but I can't relate it in my situation.

My situation is, I have a column called `date_of_mem` in `tbl_members`. I need to count how many member did register in that particular month and year.

For Example:

I have a table called `tbl_members` with column named `id`,`fname`,`mname`,`lname` and `date_of_mem` and so forth.

Now, I want to have this result:

```
Year | January | February | March | April | May | June | July ...
2013 | 100     | 250      | 50    | 60    | 300 | 280  | 125  ...
2014 | 101     | 240      | 20    | 40    | 200 | 180  | 145  ...
```

How to do this in MySQL.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      year(date_of_mem) as yr,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as january,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as february,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as march,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as april,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as may,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as june,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as july,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as august,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as september,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as october,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as november,
            sum(case when month(date_of_mem) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as december
from        tbl_members
group by    year(date_of_mem)
```

Comment: Hi @Brian DeMilia, Thanks, It really work. Can you give me some explanation on this syntax? Thanks Again.

Comment: `year()` and `month()` are mysql date and time functions that convert a given date to the year and month number respectively. The `case` statement inside of each `sum` represents conditional aggregation. For instance, in the `january` column, you are summing up 1s for each January date, and 0s for each non-January date, thus counting only January dates. You're grouping by the year associated with each date_of_mem value as well, so there's a conditional count for each year (rather than all years collectively).

Comment: Thanks @Brian DeMilia. It is useful.

Comment: how to perform on dynamic sets of records .This is were mssql beats the mysql since mssql has a very powerful in built pivot fucntion and mysql doesn't  !